# Dynamically rearrange display order of PHP code blocks on SQL query results?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

How do I dynamically rearrange six PHP code blocks based on the content of a complicated SQL query when generating a cached static page?

I have six functionally identical PHP code blocks (an example is included below) that each display the Top 5 performances for one of six games.

I wrapped the PHP code into a `function`, but had issues with the SQL queries failing.  This was solved by sending the database connector variable as a function argument, and that initial oversight was as annoying to figure out as it was dumb for me to make.

Here is base SQL query I designed to generate an average score for one of the six games, the other five are functionally identical.

```
$my_var1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT AVG(score) FROM (SELECT g1_score AS score FROM game_1) TMP");
```

And here is code in the custom function for displaying one of the six Top 5 score blocks:

```
function t5_game_1($connection) {
print "<p>Game 1</p>\n";
print "<table style='margin: 0 auto;'>\n";
$count = 0;
$A = mysqli_query($connection, "
SELECT players.Pname
     , game_1.g1_score
     , game_1.DVN 
  FROM players 
  LEFT 
  JOIN game_1 
    ON players.PID = game_1.PID 
 WHERE game_1.g1_seen = 'Y' 
 ORDER 
    BY game_1.g1_score DESC 
 LIMIT 5
     ");
IF ($AA = mysqli_fetch_array($A)) {
  do {
      print "<tr><td class='w3-left-align'>{$AA[0]}</td><td class='w3-right-align'>{$AA[1]}</td>";
      SWITCH ($AA[2]) {
          CASE 1:
              print "<td class='w3-theme-d5'>Advanced</td>\n";
              break;
          CASE 2:
              print "<td class='w3-theme-d5'>Intermediate</td>\n";
              break;
          CASE 3:
              print "<td class='w3-theme-d5'>Beginner</td>\n";
              break;
          DEFAULT:
              print "<td class='w3-theme-d5'>Beginner</td>\n";
              break;
      }
      $count++;
  } while ($AA = mysqli_fetch_array($A));

}
IF ($count < 5) {
  do {
      print "<tr><td colspan='3'>[Your name could be here]</td></tr>\n";
      $count++;
  } while ($count < 5);
}
print "</table>\n";
}
```

**UPDATE:** I found parts of my answer, and have a working solution that is a kludge, see the answer below.

Comment: I would try and push as much of the data management as possible to the database query. Any way you can add a simplified question summary to your post? Im confused as to what the actual question is.

Comment: Was there a question somewhere?

Comment: @JasonJoslin I could try and simplify the question a bit more.   I can't use SQL queries to build HTML output.   I need to be able to arrange the six display blocks from the PHP based on the results of the SQL queries.

Comment: @strawberry Yes, there was. "How do I dynamically organize six php code blocks' output based on the results of several SQL queries."

Comment: @Sandor Dosa are the php code blocks you refer to the of cases blocks in your switch statement?

Comment: @JasonJoslin No, there are six iterations of the entire code block shared, only differences are the Game names and database table.field names.

Comment: `There are six games so there will be a separate query for each` I don't understand the logic of this statement

Comment: @Strawberry there is a separate table for each game.  I run the SQL query to get the average of the score column for each table, thus six queries.

Comment: But why is there a separate table for each game?

Comment: @Strawberry Because Bowling doesn't have field goals and Football doesn't have spares.  Each of the six games is tracked independent of the others because of different scoring criterion are used to reach the final score for a given performance.  I was vague on these points for brevities sake.

Comment: Brevity? Really? Still, score is common to all games, so there is an argument to say store scores in a master table. Even if you don't agree, you can still use union to gather all the common data from all the tables - so executing one query instead of 6.

Comment: Also, note that `LEFT 
      JOIN game_1... WHERE game_1.g1_seen = 'Y'` is the same as `INNER JOIN game_1`

Comment: @Strawberry Please see the answer I've posted with my working solution and check me on the use of UNION as you have suggested.

Comment: Not without some DDLs. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I think I've added what you asked for.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec7e97/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

After having a new table suggested to store the information into an intermediate step, I decided to go with a cached page generated on an hourly cron-job.  This allows me to be as complex as I want with the SQL query, as it only runs once an hour.  Which lead to this monster SQL query assigned to `$my_var1`:  [SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec7e97/1/0)

```
SELECT
    game,
    average
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        '1' AS game,
        AVG(g1score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game1Score AS g1score
        FROM
            game1
    ) tmp1
) tmp2
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '2' AS game,
        AVG(g2score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game2Score AS g2score
        FROM
            game2
    ) tmp3
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '3' AS game,
        AVG(g3score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game3Score AS g3score
        FROM
            game3
    ) tmp4
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '4' AS game,
        AVG(g4score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game4Score AS g4score
        FROM
            game4
    ) tmp5
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '5' AS game,
        AVG(g5score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game5Score AS g5score
        FROM
            game5
    ) tmp7
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '6' AS game,
        AVG(g6score) AS average
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Game6Score AS g6score
        FROM
            game6
    ) tmp8
)
UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT
        '7' AS game,
        '999' AS average
)
ORDER BY
    average
DESC
```

This returns this dataset:

[image: Screencap of PHPMyAdmin Query Results]

This is a format that I can use a simple SWITCH/CASE to call the functions containing the Top5 score displays in the desired order:

```
do { 
    SWITCH ($my_query_result) {
        CASE 1:
            t5_game_1($connection);
            BREAK;
        CASE 2:
            t5_game_2($connection);
            BREAK;
        CASE 3:
            t5_game_3($connection);
            BREAK;
        CASE 4:
            t5_game_4($connection);
            BREAK;
        CASE 5:
            t5_game_5($connection);
            BREAK;
        CASE 6:
            t5_game_6($connection);
            BREAK;
    }
} WHILE ($my_query_result = mysqli_fetch_array($my_var1));
```

(Yes, the lack of a DEFAULT CASE or a CASE 7 is intentional)

Thing is, for some really odd reason, this was not returning the intended results when live on the web.  I never figured out what the problem was, only a patch to get it to work reliably.  Perhaps you have spotted the fix in the last element of the monster query or maybe the first row of the results?

The first row of the result would not parse.  It would always drop down to the DEFAULT action no matter what game was on top.  I therefore added a supernumerary outlier to always lead the result set and getting trashed by whatever was causing the issue. The remaining six rows (which return null if they have no data) are passed into the SWITCH/CASE and generate the six blocks of Top 5 scores for the league.

This is what I would normally consider an UGLY solution, but it works.  Though I wish I could figure out why the first row of the result set always fails but the remaining rows don't.